# Connectivity test using bash and curl

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to write a script to test if my firewall is blocking multiple pages. When I try to read one or multiple lines from command line I get a -ne: unitary operator expected error.

This is my attempt:

```
sh test www.3232.com.pe
www.3232.com.pe
test: line 7: [: -ne: unary operator expected
$ cat test
#!/bin/sh

for var in "$@"
do    
  echo $var 
  res=`curl -s -I $var | grep HTTP/1.1 | awk {'print $2'}`
    if [ $res -ne 200 ]
    then
    echo "Error on $var"
    fi
done
```

Comment: use two brackets: `if [[ $res -ne 200 ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider what happens if `curl` does not successfully connect:

```
res=`curl -s -I $var | grep HTTP/1.1 | awk {'print $2'}`
if [ $res -ne 200 ]
```

If `curl` does not get any headers, or does not get a HTTP/1.1 header, then the pipline in the first command outputs nothing and `res` is assigned to nothing.  In that case, the test in the second line will fail with an `unexpected operator` error.

You need to first test that `res` is nonempty.  And, if it is empty, take an appropriate action.

Comment: Thanks. I used this: if [ -z "$res" ] || [ $res -ne 200 ]